# Exclude directories jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I recently installed `jshint`.

And im trying to run:

```
jshint /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/src/ --reporter=jslint > /home/user/Desktop/jshint.xml --exclude pattern

jshint --help

-exclude STRING   Exclude files matching the given filename pattern 
                     (same as .jshintignore)
--exclude-path STRINGPass in a custom jshintignore file path
```

I just test with a jshintignore file and with several patterns and its still not working...

How can i 
exclude from command line this directories??

`*/vendor/*` all files inside of vendor like `public/js/vendor`, `jquery`...

Comment: did you try public/js/vendor/**?

Comment: yep, just ignore the pattern and still show the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass all options to the executable before redirecting output to the `jshint.xml`
file

```
jshint /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/src/ --reporter=jslint  --exclude pattern > /home/user/Desktop/jshint.xml
```